# Javascript - How to list all the declared classes in a file in javascript

Tags: javascript, class, autocomplete, ecmascript-6

I am implementing the autosuggestions feature for a web-based JS editor. While the user is typing, I want to show him suggestions of all the variables, functions, and classes already declared or used by himself only. I can get variables and functions from `window`, but I am not able to get the list of classes declared. Let say following is the code entered till now:

```js
class FooClass {
  constructor() {
    console.log("I am the constructor of ECMA6 class");
  }
};
```

After declaring the class, if the user enters Foo, I want to show him suggestions as `FooClass`.

Comment: So, are you manually parsing the saw text that the user entered?

Comment: @Cerbrus, Whenever the user presses Ctrl-Space, I am currently investigating the window object, and returning the result accordingly. I am also investigating worker thread's self object for suggestions. So to fetch classes from worker thread, I need the list of classes declared.

Comment: _"investigating the window object"_? What do you mean? Are you automatically running the code the user enters?

Comment: @Cerbrus, it is Chrome developer tools kind of application, So after user types valid JS code, I am executing it and keeping the scope same for the next code to be entered.

Comment: You don't want to rely on the code running for those code suggestions, though... You'd be better off parsing the code input field for `class <someName>` parts

Comment: @mikeapr4 I am using Codemirror for my editor application

Comment: @Cerbrus in case user import some module, then autocomplete suggestions wouldn't be correct. As there can be scoping problem.

Answer (score 0):

Most IDEs perform autocomplete and other intelligent refactors and defect detection using [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree).

One of the most well-known Javascript AST tools is [Esprima](http://esprima.org), which along with parsing Javascript, it also runs in JS (both browser and node).

Here's a demo it provides of how it can be used for autocomplete:
http://esprima.org/demo/autocomplete.html

If you are creating a web-based JS editor, this tool will likely save you a *lot* of time, don't re-invent the wheel.

**In the context of CodeMirror,** you might find this helpful:
https://github.com/maxogden/javascript-editor

> codemirror + esprima powered html5 javascript editor component

Comment: esprima is simply parsing the file for keywords. It is not doing any validity check before showing suggestions. And maxogden does not support ECMA6. It is specifying `class` as invalid keyword.

Comment: http://esprima.org/demo/validate.html - also, maxogden may not support ECMA6, but esprima does (first bullet on it's homepage) - I'm not saying it will be an out-of-the-box solution, but it'll be a lot easier than trying to recreate this reliably yourself.